# Excel VBA Large Table, Add Comments Vlookup, After Hitting Command Button

Tags: vba, excel, vlookup

I have a large table and the information I'm wanting to add comments to falls within `Range(D11:CY148)`. I have two tabs - "Finish Matrix" (main) and "list" (hidden - has 2 columns).

I have two issues.

First issue - Code works to a degree, after I type my values within a cell it automatically adds comments based off info in another sheet. The problem is there is too many cells to be manually typing into and if I copy and paste the code doesn't run. I created a CommandButton and wanted it to refresh the entire table with comments depending if the cells had the values that fall within "list". I tried to create a call out to Worksheet_Change but to no avail. (I'm a beginner so it'll help if you explain)

Second issue - I'm assuming it'll get fixed with whatever suggestion that works. Occasionally after typing into a cell I would get an error. Can't remember the error name but it is one of the common ones, atm the error isn't popping up but surely it'll come back since I didn't do anything different to the code.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
If Intersect(Target, Columns("A:CX")) Is Nothing Then _
If Intersect(Target, Columns("CY")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

Dim lRow As Integer

lRow = Sheets("list").Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row

If Target.Value = vbNullString Then Target.ClearComments

For Each cell In Sheets("list").Range("A1:A" & lRow)
    If cell.Value = Target.Value Then
        Target.AddComment
        Target.Comment.Text Text:=cell.Offset(0, 1).Value
    End If
Next cell

End Sub
```

Thanks for any and all help!

Comment: What does your data look like and what part is not working when you say it works "to a degree"?

Comment: @FernandoJ.Rivera It works - the degree part is that it only updates with a comment after I input a value within the cell. Picture all that data filled with variations of integers and sometimes integers with letters. 1, 2, A1, B1, etc... Each letter corresponds to an activity type which is what I want to go inside the comments. The code works perfectly if I input manually. What we normally do is copy a large section and paste it one over each week so I'm not looking to manually input each cell, I need it to refresh the entire Range after click the Update Button placed at the top of the sheet

Comment: When you update multiple cells at once (as in a copy/paste or when using Ctrl-Enter) then `Target` is not a single cell but a Range containing multiple cells.  Any Worksheet_Change event handler has to account for that possibility.

Comment: @TimWilliams to a small degree I understand what you mean, I don't however, have the technical understanding of this language to know how to apply what you are saying.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Untested, but this will take all the values in `Range(D11:CY148)` and add a comment based on a lookup from Sheet "list".

```
Sub testy()
    Dim arr As Variant, element As Variant
    Dim i As Long, j As Long, listItems As Long, rwLast As Long, clLast As Long
    Dim comm As String
    Dim rng As Range, cell As Range

    listItems = Sheets("list").Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row
    rwLast = Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row ' Adjust to fit your needs
    clLast = Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Column 'Idem

    Set rng = Sheets("list").Range("A1:A" & listItems)
    arr = Range("D11:CY148").Value

    With Worksheets("Finish Matrix")
    For i = 1 To rwLast - 10 'Adjust to make it more general, this is pretty rough
        For j = 1 To clLast - 3 'Idem
        If i = 3 Then
        End If
            comm = ""
            For Each cell In rng
                If arr(i, j) = cell.Value Then
                    comm = comm & Chr(13) & cell.Offset(0, 1).Value
                End If
            Next cell
            If Not (comm = "") Then
                .Cells(10, 3).Offset(i, j).ClearComments
                .Cells(10, 3).Offset(i, j).AddComment
                .Cells(10, 3).Offset(i, j).Comment.Text Text:=comm

            End If
        Next j
    Next i
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: It works really well, but not through the entire sheet and not multiple times. I'm assuming it has something to do with the part where you give me room to adjust. What do 10 and 3 represent? When I hit the button again, it gives me a 1004 error.

Comment: It's giving you an error because it's trying to add a comment on a cell that already has one. add `.Cells(10, 3).Offset(i, j).clearcomments` before adding and it should work as intended, even after multiple uses.

Comment: So close Fernando! Works well tested changing the same cell multiple times. However, only works on the first half of the table. For some reason it doesn't do the whole range we set?

Comment: I had a typo, I had `For j = i`, where it should have read `For j = 1`. It should work as expected now.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Works! Any idea why Run-time error 9 subscript out of range pops up? When I debug, `If arr(i, j) = cell.Value Then ` is highlighted. It still works throughout the entire sheet perfectly this error just comes up after.

Comment: **Update:** Because of this error I think it's not allowing the script to clear old comments on cells that no longer have a value in them

Comment: That happens because of the lines where I use `Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell)`. You probably have an used range that goes beyond the `D11:CY148^ range. Since I don't know what your data looks like, I can't do much there. Try looking on this forum for methods to define the last row and column of your table and see which one works for you.

Comment: So picture a giant calendar and the range is the days within the calendar where each day has a value depending on the work going on in that area. D11:CY148 is all the days. I'm not understanding why I have to define the last columns & rows if I have a range where the code needs to work within?

Comment: Change to `rwLast = 148` and `clLast =103` then

Answer (score 1):

You are basically missing the `For Each Cell in Target` part...

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim wsMain As Worksheet, wsList As Worksheet
Dim cell As Range
Dim vCommentList As Variant
Dim i As Long, lLastRow As Long
Dim sValue As String

    On Error GoTo ErrHandler
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.EnableEvents = False

    Set wsMain = Target.Parent
    Set Target = Intersect(Target, wsMain.Range("D11:CY148"))
    If Target Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    Set wsList = wsMain.Parent.Sheets("list")
    lLastRow = LastRow(1, wsList)
    ' Read Comment List into Variant (for speed)
    vCommentList = wsList.Range("A1:B" & lLastRow)

    Target.ClearComments
    ' This...For each Cell in Target...is what you were missing.
    For Each cell In Target
        sValue = cell
        For i = 1 To UBound(vCommentList)
            If sValue = vCommentList(i, 1) Then
                AddComment cell, CStr(vCommentList(i, 2))
                Exit For
            End If
        Next
    Next

ErrHandler:
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then Debug.Print Err.Description
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Proper way to find last row ...

```
Public Function LastRow(Optional Col As Integer = 1, Optional Sheet As Excel.Worksheet) As Long
    If Sheet Is Nothing Then Set Sheet = Application.ActiveSheet
    LastRow = Sheet.Cells(Sheet.Rows.Count, Col).End(xlUp).Row
End Function
```

Add Comment Sub the allows appending is needed...

```
Public Sub AddComment(Target As Range, Text As String)
    If Target.Count = 1 Then
        If Target.Comment Is Nothing Then
            Target.AddComment Text
        Else
            Target.Comment.Text Target.Comment.Text & vbLf & Text
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Removed `If sValue = vbNullString Then cell.ClearComments` in favor of just `Target.ClearComments` at the start, because it wasn't clearing the existing comments, like you'll want it to.

Comment: Thanks for your efforts, how exactly do I use them? I tried introducing it in the sheet within the command button code and nothing happened. Tried making them modules but I'm not technical enough to know how to get them to work together?

Comment: Just paste it into to module for that sheet that you are going to be pasting your data into...everything else is automatic...`Worksheet_Change` will get triggered when you change any value on the sheet, i.e. paste your data.